# Q-Learning policy doesn't agree with Value/Policy Iteration

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, q-learning, markov

I am playing with pymdptoolbox. It has a built-in problem of forest management. It can generate a transition matrix `P` and `R` by specifying a state value for forest function (default value is 3). The implementation of `Q-Learning`, `PolicyIteration` and `ValueIteration` to find the optimal policy is straightforward. However by creating a slightly more complicated problem by changing the state to a bit larger value than 4 (from 5 onwards), only `PI` and `VI` return the same policy while `QL` cannot find the optimal policy. This is very surprising and puzzling. Can anyone help me understand why is this for `QL` in this package?

By looking at the raw code of `QL` (using epsilon-greedy), it seems it ties the probability with iteration number, i.e. `prob = 1 - (1/log(n+2))` and the learning rate is (`1/math.sqrt(n+2)`). Is there any specific reason why tying probability/learning rate to the iteration number, instead of making them independent variables (the code itself can be modified easily though).

I think my biggest puzzle is to understand why `QL` fails to find the policy for a vanilla problem. Thanks.

```
from mdptoolbox.mdp import ValueIteration, QLearning, PolicyIteration
from mdptoolbox.example import forest

Gamma = 0.99

states = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 20, 30, 50, 70, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000]

compare_VI_QI_policy = [] # True or False
compare_VI_PI_policy = []

for state in states:

    P, R = forest(state)

    VI = ValueIteration(P, R, Gamma)
    PI = PolicyIteration(P, R, Gamma)
    QL = QLearning(P, R, Gamma)

    ## run VI
    VI.run()

    # run PI
    PI.run()

    # run QL
    QL.run()

    compare_VI_QI_policy.append(QL.policy == VI.policy)
    compare_VI_PI_policy.append(VI.policy == PI.policy)

print compare_VI_QI_policy
print compare_VI_PI_policy
```